# Why aren't these two Mongoose code patterns equivalent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The following code pattern works:

```
   collectionModel.findOne({"username" : username})
                  .exec()
                  .then(function (err, docs) { console.log(err); });
```

Yet the following (seemingly equivalent) code pattern doesn't:

```
var nameFunction = function (err, docs) {
    console.log(err);
}

collectionModel.findOne({"username" : username})
               .exec()
               .then(nameFunction(err, docs));
```

Indeed, this latter code patterns throws the error that "`err` is undefined".  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the reference to the function:

```
collectionModel.findOne({"username" : username})
               .exec()
               .then(nameFunction);
```

Your code is *calling* the function (or trying to), and then (if the attempt didn't fail with an error) would pass the *return value* to `.then()`.

A function reference by itself is a reference to a function that can be tossed around like any other value. When a function reference is followed by a parenthesized argument list, that's a function call.

Comment: Wow -- such a stupid error on my part.  Thanks for pointing it out.